# How to determine a vector using 2 Points in Android map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, vector

I'm trying to do some advanced features with android maps and to do that I need to do some operations on vectors. Now - I read the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/point-in-polygon-aka-hit-test) and it gave me some hints and tips. However, there is a part which I don't understand. Please allow me to quote this:

> Now that we have the ray with its start and end coordinates, the problem shifts from "is the point within the polygon" to "how often intersects the ray a polygon side". Therefor we can't just work with the polygon points as before (for the bounding box), now we need the actual sides. A side is always defined by two points.
>
> side 1: (X1/Y1)-(X2/Y2) side 2:
>   (X2/Y2)-(X3/Y3) side 3:
>   (X3/Y3)-(X4/Y4)

So my understanding is that every side of the triangle is actually a vector. But how is it possible to substract 2 points? Let's say I got a triangle with 3 vertices: A(1,1) , B(2,2), C (1,3). So according to that, I have to do, for example, (1,1)-(2,2) in order to calculate one of the sides. The question is how to do it programatically in java/android? Below I'm attaching the code which I already developed:

```
    /** Creating the containers for screen 
     *  coordinates taken from geoPoints
     */

    Point point1_screen = new Point();
    Point point2_screen = new Point();
    Point point3_screen = new Point();

    /* Project them from the map to screen */
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point1, point1_screen);
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point2, point2_screen);
mapView.getProjection().toPixels(point3, point3_screen);

    int xA = point1_screen.x;
    int yA = point1_screen.y;

    int xB = point2_screen.x;
    int yB = point2_screen.y;

    int xC = point3_screen.x;
    int yC = point3_screen.y;

    int[] xPointsArray = new int[3];
    int[] yPointsArray = new int[3];

    xPointsArray[0] = xA;
    xPointsArray[1] = xB;
    xPointsArray[2] = xC;

    yPointsArray[0] = yA;
    yPointsArray[1] = yB;
    yPointsArray[2] = yC;

    Arrays.sort(xPointsArray);

    int xMin = xPointsArray[0];
    int yMin = yPointsArray[0];

    int xMax = xPointsArray[xPointsArray.length-1];
    int yMax = xPointsArray[xPointsArray.length-1]; 

    int e = (xMax - xMin) / 100;                                    // for ray calcultions

    int width = mapView.getWidth();
    int height = mapView.getHeight();

    if(pPoint.x < xMin || pPoint.x > xMax || pPoint.y > yMin || pPoint.y < yMax)
    {

        DisplayInfoMessage(pPoint.x + " < " + xMin + " AND "  + pPoint.x + " > " + xMax + " || " + pPoint.y + " < " + yMin + " AND "  + pPoint.y + " > " + yMax );
    //  DisplayInfoMessage("Minimum is: "+  yPointsArray[0] + " and the maximum is: "+ yPointsArray[xPointsArray.length-1]);

    }
    else
    {
         GeoPoint start_point = new GeoPoint(xMin - e, pPoint.y);
         Point start_point_container = new Point();  
         mapView.getProjection().toPixels(start_point, start_point_container);

            int a, b, c, tx, ty;
            int d1, d2, hd;
            int ix, iy;
            float r;
            // calculating vector for 1st line

            tx = xB - xA;
            ty = yB - yA;

            // equation for 1st line

            a = ty;
            b = tx;
            c = xA*a - yA*b;

            // get distances from line for line 2

            d1 = a*xB + b*yB + c;
            d2 = a*pPoint.x + b*pPoint.y + c;



            DisplayInfoMessage("You clicked inside the triangle!" + "TRIANGLE POINTS: A("+xA+","+yA+") B("+xB+","+yB+") C("+xC+","+yC+")");
    }
```

The pPoint hold the coordinates of the point which user clicked. I hope that I explained my problem well enough. Can someone give me some help with that? Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an Android developer, but I see that `android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape` lacks the `contains()` method found in `java.awt.Shape`. It appears you'll have to develop your own test, as suggested in the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578) you cited. In addition, you might want to look at [crossing/winding number](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0103/algorithm_0103.htm) algorithms.

> But how is it possible to subtract 2 points?

Subtraction of vectors is well [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector#Addition_and_subtraction), and easily [implemented](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/kineticmodel/code#Vector) in Java. Given two points as vectors, the components of the difference represent the tangent (slope) of a line connecting the points. The example in the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578) implements this in the following lines:

```
//get tangent vector for line 1
tx = v1x2 - v1x1;
ty = v1y2 - v1y1;
```

The foundation for the approach shown is discussed further in [*Line and Segment Intersections*](http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0104/algorithm_0104B.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the hint trashgod - that helped.